# The Semantics of XML Schema Extension 

Tags: xsd

Intuitively, "extension" means add something to base type, not to modify base type. The following XSD

```
<complexType name="B">
    <attribute name="A1" type="int" use="required" />
    <anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="strict" />
</complexType>
<complexType name="D">
    <complexContent >
        <extension base="tns:B">
            <!--???-->
            <attribute name="A1" type="int" use="optional" />
            <anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

should not compile. But XML Schema compiler(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema) do not throw errors. What's the rational of this counter-intuition design?

Comment: I know the reason: XML schema is "structural typing", not "nominal typing"......

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the Schema:

- In D, you are trying to add attribute A1 a second time.

Listing something in the extension adds it to the definition.  In this case "A1" is already there.  Any extended instance needs to be a valid instance of the base.  If A1 were not present it would not be a valid member of the base.

It looks like you need to restrict the B type if you want to make it optional.